# What's the difference of two situations?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics

[image]

[image]

Both situation seems similar.
However, acceleration of each situation was different.
Also, EOM was different.
What's the difference?

Comment: What does EOM stand for?

Comment: EOM stand for Equation of Motion

Comment: I'm temporarily closing this question as off-topic because [most of the information is trapped in a screenshot](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/10563/44126).

Comment: It looks like a poorly posed problem to me.  In 9-15 we don't know if the rope is coiled  so the coil will spin, or if the rope effectively peels of the inside of the coil.  In the latter case, the rope will need to spin (or twist).  However, I suspect the point of the comparing 9-15 to 9-21 is that in the 9-21 case the whole rope must be accelerated at the same time, while in 9-15 only a very small portion of the rope above the hole needs to be accelerated, while the rest is unaffected until it finds itself being pulled toward the hole.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is actually a good test on the concept of inelastic collisions.

In the second situation, both energy and momentum are conserved as the entire rope accelerates smoothly.

In the first situation, only momentum is conserved. As each tiny segment of rope reaches the hole, it is suddenly accelerated to the same speed as the rope that is already falling (as it was not moving just the instant before). Therefore, the process is inelastic and energy isn't conserved.

Comment: I don't see why energy is not conserved?  Are you saying the deformation of the rope is causing wasted heat energy in the rope?

Comment: @PhysicsDave: In the second situation, the entire rope accelerates at the same time and at the same rate, due to the weight of the hanging part. In the first situation, only the rope that is hanging is accelerating and the rest of the rope is still stationary on the table. The acceleration from zero to the speed of falling is assumed to be instantaneous, and therefore it is inelastic.